# Parse parameter in shell script

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, shell, unix

all

I am trying to write a shell script(lets call it mysh) which calls *another shell scripts* (lets name it origin).

The origin script takes several parameters the syntax looks like this:

`./origin.sh /A=appname,/U=admin,/LL=ADMINISTRATOR`

In mysh script, that origin script would be called, could someone please let me know how to parse those arguments (/A,/U,/LL) in the shell scripts? By defining variables?

This is supposed to be a easy task, and please think it in a simple way :D

Thanks to all

Comment: So mysh.sh is a shell script, and you want to execute origin.sh with appname, admin and administrator arguments?
Why is the syntax written like /A=appname?

Comment: Since you are doing this on linux/unix, is there a good reason why you are not using linux/unix-style options which could be easily parsed by `bash`?

Comment: Your script, which *calls* `origin.sh`, is trying to parse the arguments to `origin.sh`? Why? Aren't you just going to need to hand them to `origin.sh` verbatim anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Change the "/" to "-" and the "," to space, you can use getopts to parse and extract the arguments. See here for examples:

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Alternatively, get rid of the "/" and change the "," for space, then each argument becomes a param=value, so you can sue "eval" to set these are environment variables.

Something like:

```
for P in $*
do
   eval $P
done
```

Comment: Just `for P; do` will iterate over `"$@"` by default. `$*` is buggy -- splits on IFS and expands globs -- don't use it unless you know exactly *why* you're using `$*` instead of `"$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will parse into an associative array:

```sh
declare -A settings=( )

for arg; do                               # iterate over all arguments
  if [[ $arg = /* ]]; then                # ignore ones not starting with slashes
    IFS=, read -r -a items <<<"$arg"      # split them out by commas...
    for item in "${items[@]}"; do         # ...iterate over what we got by splitting
      if [[ $item = *=* ]]; then          # ...ignore entries that don't have an =
        settings[${item%%=*}]=${item#*=}  # ...the part before the first = is the key
                                          #    and the rest is the value.
      fi
    done
  fi
done
```

This can be read out as follows:

```
echo "App name is ${settings[A]}. User is ${settings[U]}."
```